# XAMPP Apache Service detected with wrong path help me

Tags: apache, error-handling, xampp

I don't know how to fix it

[Apache]    XAMPP Apache is already running on port 1234

[Apache]   XAMPP Apache is already running on port 8181

[Tomcat]  Tomcat Service detected with wrong path

[Tomcat]  Change XAMPP Tomcat and Control Panel settings or

[Tomcat]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first

[Tomcat]  Found Path: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 
7.0\bin\Tomcat7.exe" //RS//Tomcat7

[Tomcat]   Expected Path: c:\xampp\tomcat\bin\tomcat7.exe //RS//Tomcat7

Answer (score 0):

The error is simply saying that tomcat is already installed and running. it should be started from your **expected path** but already running through **found path** as clearly stated in your exception.

So you have to first **stop or uninstall or change the port number** of already running apache. you can follow the steps to uninstall the apache from http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000005720